# "cf. with" vs "cf."?

Tags: abbreviations

The abbreviation cf. according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.) should be read as *compare*. Which, therefore, of the following would be a more correct statement:

> 1) The properties of the electric field are given below (*cf. with* the magnetic field).
>
> 2)The properties of the electric field are given below (*cf.* the magnetic field).

Comment: The way *cf.* is used is for a reference to immediately follow (cf. *reference*). It's a formulaic expression, and not normally considered a simple abbreviation for the word *compare*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although *cf.* has the sense of *compare*, it is a formulaic expression and not a drop-in replacement for *compare*.

Several references clarify this by expanding the meaning to "compare *with*" - e.g. [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cf) and [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cf.).

Usage guides with examples also show *cf.* followed immediately by the reference. Examples: your [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.) (cf. Vehicle Code section 4321 ...) and [APA style](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2010/05/its-all-latin-to-me.html)  (cf. Zeller & Williams, 2007).

> Which, therefore, of the following would be a more correct statement ...

The second (cf. the magnetic field) would be better since it doesn't add the word *with*, but *the magnetic field* is not a reference that supports the assertion. Try this instead:

> The properties of the electric field are given below *(see also: magnetic field)*.